# Pivot in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I have a table in the below format

```
PN PI gender dob
1  11 M      YYYYMMDD 
1  12 F      YYYYMMDD 
2  21 F      YYYYMMDD 
2  22 M      YYYYMMDD 
3  31 M      YYYYMMDD
4  35 M      YYYYMMDD
4  36 M      YYYYMMDD
```

I am trying to print it in the below format

```
PN Primary_gender joint_gender primary_dob  secondary_dob
1  M              F            YYYYMMDD     YYYYMMDD
2  F              M            YYYYMMDD     YYYYMMDD
3  M              [NULL]       YYYYMMDD     [NULL]
4  M              M            YYYYMMDD     YYYYMMDD
```

.
.
.

The logic here is for every PN the min(PI) is the primary and max(PI) is joint . I tried doing a case statement with min and max but i am stuck to get the right answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are there always only two rows for each `PN`? (If not, please add some more examples, such as 1-row and 3-rows.) Do the values for `PI` follow any rule?

Comment: Added more records, since some PN might have only one record and the PI of the joint owner is just one more than the primary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select pn,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then gender end) as primary_gender,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then gender end) as joint_gender,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then dob end) as primary_dob,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then dob end) as joint_dob
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by pn order by pi) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by pn
```

Comment: Gordon strikes again! :)